# Undefined symbol

Tags: c

I'm getting an `undefined symbol` error even though I think I've defined it okay.  From reading other posts and Googling, it seems that the linker is failing to find the appropriate symbol.  I'm new to C so I'm sure I'm just missing something stupid.

```
glen-urbans-macbook-pro:everybit glurban$ make
gcc -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c99 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I. -m64 -DBUILD_64 -c bitarray.c -o bitarray.o
gcc -o everybit main.o ktiming.o bitarray.o tests.o -arch x86_64 -framework CoreServices
gcc -o everybit_harvey main.o ktiming.o bitarray_harvey.o tests.o -arch x86_64 -framework CoreServices
Undefined symbols:
  "_bitarray_reverse", referenced from:
      _test_reverse in tests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [everybit_harvey] Error 1
```

In tests.c:

```
#include "bitarray.h"
...

/* Peform a reversal operation on test_ba. */
static void testutil_reverse(size_t bit_off, size_t bit_len) {
  assert(test_ba != NULL);
  bitarray_reverse(test_ba, bit_off, bit_len);
  if (test_verbose) {
    bitarray_fprint(stdout, test_ba);
    fprintf(stdout, " rotate off=%llu, len=%llu\n",
        (unsigned long long) bit_off, (unsigned long long) bit_len);
  }
}

static void test_reverse(void) {
  testutil_frmstr("10000101");
  testutil_reverse(0, 8);
  testutil_expect("10100001", 4);
}

test_case_t test_cases[] = {
  test_headerexamples,
  test_8bit,
  test_moreflips,
  // ADD YOUR TEST CASES HERE
    test_reverse,
  NULL // This marks the end of all test cases. Don't change this!
};
```

In bitarray.c,

```
/* Reverse a bit array */
void bitarray_reverse(bitarray_t *ba, size_t bit_off, size_t bit_len){
    size_t tmp;
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < bit_len/2; i++){
        tmp = bitarray_get(ba, bit_off + i);
        bitarray_set(ba, bit_off + i, bitarray_get(ba,bit_off + bit_len - 1 - i));
        bitarray_set(ba, bit_off + bit_len - 1 - i, tmp);
    }
}
```

In bitarray.h:

```
void bitarray_reverse(bitarray_t *ba, size_t bit_off, size_t bit_len);
```

TIA

Comment: You showed the source code for bitarray.c but are actually using bitarray_harvey.c.  Which probably doesn't contain bitarray_reverse()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bitarray.o is compiled into an object file `everybit` **BUT** there is ***no reference*** in this line to `everybit` hence the undefined symbols...

```
gcc -o everybit_harvey main.o ktiming.o bitarray_harvey.o tests.o -arch x86_64 -framework CoreServices
Undefined symbols:
  "_bitarray_reverse", referenced from:
      _test_reverse in tests.o
ld: symbol(s) not found
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [everybit_harvey] Error 1
```

What is `_harvey`referring to?

Comment: `_harvey` refers to the original version of the code (it's getting modified in the non harvey version).  If I understand correctly what's going on: maybe tests.o calls either everybit or everybit_harvey, and fails for the second one because bitarray_reverse is not in there?

Comment: Maybe unsorted needs to `gcc -O3 -DNDEBUG -std=c99 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -I. -m64 -DBUILD_64 -c bitarray_harvey.c -o bitarray_harvey.o`. How is `bitarray_harvey.o` created?